# CloudFront and S3 redirect to specific html (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So I have the following problem, I need to redirect a specific site for example `example/page.html`, for which I don't have a html document, to a specific html page `index_error.html`, for which I have an html document.

I already have CloudFront and working site, this should be additional feature.

I created a new S3 bucket with the `index_error.html` in it, created origin for the S3 bucket, and behavior with path pattern `page.html` and origin the S3 bucket.

The thing that it's supposed to happen is when a request is made to `example/page.html`, then CF to serve `index_error.html`, but that is not happening. Instead of that I am getting an custom error page, with some of the 
`404`, `405`, `414`, `415` HTML code.

**Any ideas what I am doing wrong and now to fix this.**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.
When you say "that is not happening" What *is* happening? What happens when you trace the http traffic with Fiddler etc?
Please add this info to your original question

Comment: The expected behavior is supposed to be: when user try to open example/page.html, this page to be redirected and to be open index_error.html. This behavior is not happening. As for the trace of the http traffic I will do it first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Please don't limit your description to what is *not* happening.  Also describe the unexpected thing that **is** happening.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot sorry I am new at this, still don't know if it is explained well. Feel free to ask me anything